# Is it possible to decide in finite time whether a presentation is a presentation of a finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation

I know that all finite groups have presentations. I also know that some infinite groups have finite presentations. Is it possible to decide in finite time whether a presentation is a presentation of a finite group?

Comment: As Qiaocho has said, the answer is no. The problem is however semi-decidable in the sense that if the group is finite then it is possible to prove that it is finite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this and many other questions about finite presentations are undecidable by the [Adyan-Rabin theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533542/is-there-an-algorithm-to-check-whether-a-subset-generates-a-group/4533546#4533546).